# JSON navigation

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to implement the Websters Dictionary into this python code so that I can look up the definition of a word.

As Trigonom pointed out I can search for "shortdef" in the JSON

```
@bot.command()
async def define(ctx, *, search):
    with urllib.request.urlopen('https://dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/' + search + '?key=632c5b56-d2ec-4c66-a432-93c5a5994748') as url:
        lk = url.read()
        word_dict = json.loads(lk)
        defin = word_dict[0]['shortdef']
        print (defin)
```

I get this output when I search for "shotgun":

```
['a usually smoothbore shoulder weapon capable of firing shot at short ranges', 'an offensive football formation in which the quarterback plays a few yards behind the line of scrimmage and the other backs are scattered as flankers or slotbacks']
```

How can I get the first definition from that

https://dictionaryapi.com/products/api-collegiate-dictionary

https://dictionaryapi.com/products/json#sec-2.dt

Comment: convert the json to a dict

Comment: I did but how do I navigate it

Comment: That's not valid json -- you would need `{` at the beginning and `}` at the end to make it into a dictionary.

Comment: Also `"{bc}the procedure..."` is a multiline string which isn't valid.

Comment: then how would I be able to use this in my python code

Comment: in the first attachment you gave there is an example for the word 'voluminous'            this is how you send the request https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/voluminous?key=your-api-key                                                                                                                           and the response is a json with lots of info about that word,                                               for the simple definition go to 'shortdef' key in the end of the json

Comment: I will update my question with this @trigonom

Comment: Show the full output of `print(lk)`

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/549a422e @OneCricketeer
I searched for "boat"

Comment: Okay, so the first character being parsed is an open square bracket, meaning you have a list. Next character indicates a list of objects, so you need to loop over those objects, then check which has the field you want.

Comment: can you please write this out in an answer, I don't quite understand this

Comment: I got a small breakthrough, I'll update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def define(ctx, *, search):
    with urllib.request.urlopen('https://dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/' + search + '?key=632c5b56-d2ec-4c66-a432-93c5a5994748') as url:
        lk = url.read()
        word_dict = json.loads(lk)
        defin = word_dict[0]['shortdef'][0]
        print (defin)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, the JSON result is a list. In particular, a list of objects.

There are multiple shortdefs, and you need to parse each object out

```
results = [x['shortdef'] for x in json.loads(lk)]
```

example output

```
[['a small vessel for travel on water',
  'ship',
  'a boat-shaped container, utensil, or device'],
 ['to place in or bring into a boat', 'to go by boat'],
 ['a pole-handled hook with a point or knob on the back used especially to pull or push a boat, raft, or log into place'],
 ['refugees fleeing by boat'],
 ['a low-cut shoe with a slip-resistant sole'],
 ['an express train for transporting passengers between a port and a city'],
 ['a small portable boat used in an amphibious military attack or in land warfare for crossing rivers or lakes'],
 ['a seaplane with a hull designed for floating'],
 ["a ship's boat of medium size used for general-purpose work"],
 ['pt boat']]
```